# Django 1.10 - Create two formsets from single queryobject

Tags: django, django-forms, django-queryset

I have `Book` model, which has `title`, and `author` string fields. `title` fields may be different, but `author` is always equal to `joey` or `martin`.

On a single page, I want to display two `formsets`, BUT I don't want to create `QuerySet` and make DB query separately for each form. Is it possible to, get all the objects at once, and then split them into separate `lists` and pass them info `formset`?

**My view function:**

```
def index(request):

    books = Book.objects.all()  # Here we will take all at once

    joey_books = []
    martin_books = []

    for book in books:  # books here are evaluated - only once!
        if book.author == 'joey':
             joey_books.push(book)
        elif book.author == 'martin':
             martin_books.push(book)

    joey_book_formset = forms.modelformset_factory(
        Book,
        form=BookForm,
        fields=['title', 'author'],
        can_delete=True, extra=1
    )

    joey_book_formset = joey_book_formset(queryset=joey_books)  # Exception raised

    martin_book_formset = forms.modelformset_factory(
        Book,
        form=BookForm,
        fields=['title', 'author'],
        can_delete=True, extra=1
    )

    martin_book_formset = martin_book_formset(queryset=martin_books)  # Exception raised

    context = {
        'joey_forms': joey_book_formset,
        'martin_forms': martin_book_formset,
    }

    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context)
```

**My expectation:**

Two formsets would be created and there would be running just one query.

**Problem**:

Following `exception` is raised:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ordered'

It is probably because `formsets` accept only `QuerySet` objects. Is there any workaround for this? Imagine I have like 50 forms on single page.. I dont want to run 50 separate queries for each formset.

Comment: Why not use a queryset for each form, i.e. `Book.objects.filter(author="joey")` and `Book.objects.all(author="martin")`? In practice I don't think that two queries will be noticeably slower than one. Even if you had 50 formsets (and I'm not sure why you would do this), I don't think that one query per formset would cause huge problems.

Comment: Becuase if query would be much more complicated, it would lead to performance issues. Moreover it may happen, that I will be working with huge amount of data.